# How to make model can take any size input when exporting model from matlab to onnx?

Tags: c#, matlab, deep-learning, ml.net, onnx

I got a model(train with Matlab) which is an FCN(Fully-Convolutional Network). Input is an image, output is the noises of the image, so our target is (input-output) which is an denoised image. Due to the FCN structure, theoretically, it should take any size of input. But I set the model input size to 50x50 for faster training. Then I export the model to ONNX(open neural network exchange) format and tried to inference on C# with Ml.Net. Then, I found that the model input size must be same as training(50x50). I want the model can inference with any size of input. How do I fix this problem? As I know in Keras, it can be setting input size as "None" for taking any size of input. But I do not know how to do it in Matlab. Does anyone has any ideas? I use the code below.
[Matlab denoisedImage](http://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/images/ref/denoiseimage.html)

Comment: The link page does not exist.

Comment: Correct link: https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/images/ref/denoiseimage.html